# build.gradle dependencies in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, build.gradle

I am developing an app using `SQLiteAssetsHelper` in Android studio and I have seen two `build.gradle` files. one is in the app folder and second is in  folder, in my (project's name) folder the `build.gradle` file contains folowing

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

but i saw most examples with `mavenCentral()` in repositories .. what should I have to do in this `build.gradle` file??..
second `build.gradle` file in app folder contains the following..

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
       compileSdkVersion 22
       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.appxone.practicesqliteassetshelper"
       minSdkVersion 8
       targetSdkVersion 22
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
  }

      dependencies {
          compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
          compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
      }
```

in github they said to use

```
compile `com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+`
```

in dependecies and to use add jar file of sqliteassetshelper in lib folder..
but im totally confuse in which build.gradle , which dependencies i have to add this compile `com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassetshelper:+` statement.. and do i change the `jcenter()` into `mavenCentral()`.. 
i have used `SQLiteOpenHelper` class but this give only bunch of codes..and stackflow give me suggestion to use `SQLiteAssetsHelper` ..please help me 
I make an `assets/databases/myDB.db` as well but now what should i do next..

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

into your module `build.gradle` file (usually it's called "app"), not in the top-level build file. So your module `build.gradle` should look like this:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
       compileSdkVersion 22
       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.appxone.practicesqliteassetshelper"
       minSdkVersion 8
       targetSdkVersion 22
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
  }
  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
      compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
  }
```

**EDIT**:
Also, you should change `buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"` to `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`, but I'd suggest you to use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` along with `targetSdkVersion 23` and `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` to support latest Android version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two gradle files. 1st is `build.gradle (Project Foo)` and the other is `build.gradle (Module : App)`. **Do not dare edit the 1st one.**

Comment: Actually you need to edit top level build.gradle sometimes, just not in this case

Comment: @IvanV Yeah. I wrote the answer considering that OP is a beginner

Comment: i havent change the buildToolVersion but sometimes it shows all data from assets folder perfectly and some time give me error of .

Answer (score 0):

Add it here:

```
dependencies {
          compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
          compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
      }
```

make changes to app:gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Replace your from:

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

To this:

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```